# Почему WP_Query возвращает лишние данные?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, запрос

Есть сайт на **wordpress**, где я хочу в определенном месте вывести содержимое произвольного поля для чего с помощью **WP_Query** запрашиваю данные по запросу у базы данных mysql.

```
<?php $otkatnye_gates = new WP_Query([
                        'post_type'     => 'section_gates',
      'post_name'     => 'otkatnye-vorota',
                        'post_status'   => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
                        'order'         => 'ASC'
                    ]); 
  var_dump($otkatnye_gates);
```

Однако, в запросе содержится вывод только постов с именем 'post_name' => 'otkatnye-vorota', а выводятся плюс ко всему еще почему-то и лишние данные с 'post_name' => 'sektsionnye-vorota'. Поясню общий тип секционных ворот подразделяется на секционные и откатные, так вот я запрашиваю именно подтип откатных. В чем причина и как решить задачу по выводу?

```
object(WP_Query)#4646 (49) { ["query"]=> array(5) { ["post_type"]=> string(13) "section_gates" ["post_name"]=> string(15) "otkatnye-vorota" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["posts_per_page"]=> int(-1) ["order"]=> string(3) "ASC" } ["query_vars"]=> array(66) { ["post_type"]=> string(13) "section_gates" ["post_name"]=> string(15) "otkatnye-vorota" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["posts_per_page"]=> int(-1) ["order"]=> string(3) "ASC" ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["m"]=> string(0) "" ["p"]=> int(0) ["post_parent"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost_id"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment_id"]=> int(0) ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["static"]=> string(0) "" ["pagename"]=> string(0) "" ["page_id"]=> int(0) ["second"]=> string(0) "" ["minute"]=> string(0) "" ["hour"]=> string(0) "" ["day"]=> int(0) ["monthnum"]=> int(0) ["year"]=> int(0) ["w"]=> int(0) ["category_name"]=> string(0) "" ["tag"]=> string(0) "" ["cat"]=> string(0) "" ["tag_id"]=> string(0) "" ["author"]=> string(0) "" ["author_name"]=> string(0) "" ["feed"]=> string(0) "" ["tb"]=> string(0) "" ["paged"]=> int(0) ["meta_key"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_value"]=> string(0) "" ["preview"]=> string(0) "" ["s"]=> string(0) "" ["sentence"]=> string(0) "" ["title"]=> string(0) "" ["fields"]=> string(0) "" ["menu_order"]=> string(0) "" ["embed"]=> string(0) "" ["category__in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["post_name__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__and"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["ignore_sticky_posts"]=> bool(false) ["suppress_filters"]=> bool(false) ["cache_results"]=> bool(true) ["update_post_term_cache"]=> bool(true) ["lazy_load_term_meta"]=> bool(true) ["update_post_meta_cache"]=> bool(true) ["nopaging"]=> bool(true) ["comments_per_page"]=> string(2) "50" ["no_found_rows"]=> bool(false) } ["tax_query"]=> object(WP_Tax_Query)#4644 (6) { ["queries"]=> array(0) { } ["relation"]=> string(3) "AND" ["table_aliases":protected]=> array(0) { } ["queried_terms"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_table"]=> string(8) "wp_posts" ["primary_id_column"]=> string(2) "ID" } ["meta_query"]=> object(WP_Meta_Query)#4645 (9) { ["queries"]=> array(0) { } ["relation"]=> NULL ["meta_table"]=> NULL ["meta_id_column"]=> NULL ["primary_table"]=> NULL ["primary_id_column"]=> NULL ["table_aliases":protected]=> array(0) { } ["clauses":protected]=> array(0) { } ["has_or_relation":protected]=> bool(false) } ["date_query"]=> bool(false) ["request"]=> string(161) "SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'section_gates' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC " ["posts"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(WP_Post)#4647 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(256) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2016-11-04 13:03:09" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-11-04 10:03:09" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(33) "Секционные ворота" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(18) "sektsionnye-vorota" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2016-11-04 13:38:32" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-11-04 10:38:32" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["guid"]=> string(62) "http://vorota.domain.ru/?post_type=section_gates&p=256" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(13) "section_gates" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [1]=> object(WP_Post)#4648 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(371) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2016-11-15 18:08:25" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-11-15 15:08:25" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(29) "Откатные ворота" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(15) "otkatnye-vorota" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2016-11-16 12:28:15" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-11-16 09:28:15" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["guid"]=> string(62) "http://vorota.domain.ru/?post_type=section_gates&p=371" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(13) "section_gates" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } } ["post_count"]=> int(2) ["current_post"]=> int(-1) ["in_the_loop"]=> bool(false) ["post"]=> object(WP_Post)#4647 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(256) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2016-11-04 13:03:09" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-11-04 10:03:09" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(33) "Секционные ворота" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(18) "sektsionnye-vorota" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2016-11-04 13:38:32" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-11-04 10:38:32" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["guid"]=> string(62) "http://vorota.domain.ru/?post_type=section_gates&p=256" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(13) "section_gates" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } ["comment_count"]=> int(0) ["current_comment"]=> int(-1) ["found_posts"]=> int(2) ["max_num_pages"]=> int(0) ["max_num_comment_pages"]=> int(0) ["is_single"]=> bool(false) ["is_preview"]=> bool(false) ["is_page"]=> bool(false) ["is_archive"]=> bool(false) ["is_date"]=> bool(false) ["is_year"]=> bool(false) ["is_month"]=> bool(false) ["is_day"]=> bool(false) ["is_time"]=> bool(false) ["is_author"]=> bool(false) ["is_category"]=> bool(false) ["is_tag"]=> bool(false) ["is_tax"]=> bool(false) ["is_search"]=> bool(false) ["is_feed"]=> bool(false) ["is_comment_feed"]=> bool(false) ["is_trackback"]=> bool(false) ["is_home"]=> bool(true) ["is_404"]=> bool(false) ["is_embed"]=> bool(false) ["is_paged"]=> bool(false) ["is_admin"]=> bool(false) ["is_attachment"]=> bool(false) ["is_singular"]=> bool(false) ["is_robots"]=> bool(false) ["is_posts_page"]=> bool(false) ["is_post_type_archive"]=> bool(false) ["query_vars_hash":"WP_Query":private]=> string(32) "24e7c084810e154f438adeaa682dc2d7" ["query_vars_changed":"WP_Query":private]=> bool(false) ["thumbnails_cached"]=> bool(false) ["stopwords":"WP_Query":private]=> NULL ["compat_fields":"WP_Query":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "query_vars_hash" [1]=> string(18) "query_vars_changed" } ["compat_methods":"WP_Query":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(16) "init_query_flags" [1]=> string(15) "parse_tax_query" } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ответе есть запрос к базе, который был составлен из ваших параметров запроса (я отформатировал запрос для лучшей читаемости):

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts 
    WHERE 1=1 
        AND wp_posts.post_type = 'section_gates' 
        AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
    ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC
```

Обратите внимание что упоминания `post_name` тут нету. В [документации](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) также нету такого параметра. Скорее всего вы имели ввиду параметр `name`